# using node-sspi with express.js

Tags: authentication

Given the code included how would I go about getting a function that returns req.connection.user without using app.use etc? Totally confused!

I want to do this in app.js. I have tried a dozen different ways but I am hitting a wall. Thanks

```
function GetUserName() {
}

--Sample code
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var nodeSSPI = require('node-sspi');
  var nodeSSPIObj = new nodeSSPI({
    retrieveGroups: true
  });
  nodeSSPIObj.authenticate(req, res, function(err){
    res.finished || next();
  });
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var out = 'Hello ' + req.connection.user + '! You belong to following groups:<br/><ul>';
  if (req.connection.userGroups) {
    for (var i in req.connection.userGroups) {
      out += '<li>'+ req.connection.userGroups[i] + '</li><br/>\n';
    }
  }
  out += '</ul>';
  res.send(out);
});
// Start server
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.get('env'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You also don't need to. All the functions where you would find it interesting to check their username will have the req object sent to it.

If you want to have a single function where you do the test and you use Express with the router you can do it like this

```js
function custom_auth(req, res, next) {
    if (req.connection.user === 'valid_username') {
        next();
        return;
    } else {
        res.status(401).send({
            message: 'Access denied'
        });
    }
}

router.get('/', custom_auth, function(req, res, next) {
    // Send your response here
}
```

When someone does a request for `'/'` they will first be sent to the `custom_auth` function. When `next();` is called, they will be sent back to
the routing function. If your authentication test fails you want to handle that in some way, in this example they just get a 403 with a JSON message.

If you don't know how to use the router and how it looks like tied into app.js, look up `express-generator` which will set up some plumbing for an Express project